# Tap event only works when finger doesnt slide

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am using jquery mobile with phone gap on IOS and i notice that the tap event is trigger only when you tap the screen without moving your finger left or right. 
Below is my bind code.

```
$(".pic-cont").on("tap",{count: "not needed"},function(event){
        console.log("Clicked");
        ....
```

I am making a game and the user will tap things on the screen quickly and what i notice is when you tap fast your finger may slide and not register the tap event. Is there any other event i can use (like a touchdown event) so when a users finger hits the screen the event is registered right away regardless if they move finger left right up down or hold.

Thanks!

Comment: You can track swipe event. http://api.jquerymobile.com/swipe/

Answer (score 3):

In case of jQuery Mobile there are few solutions, but one will work in your case.

### Solution 1 - jQuery solution

Instead of tap event you should use touchstart event. It works like tap and at the same time it is a first event to trigger during the screen swipe.

Here a code example:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){       
    $(document).on('touchstart', '#index', function(){       
        alert('touchstart');
    });
});
```

And I made you a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/vDqdD/

### Solution 2 - jQuery Mobile solution

While touchstart is a good all around solution, it wont work on older Android devices using older jQuery Mobile versions (1.1 and below).

So if you need to create a bulletproof version you should use [vmousedown](http://api.jquerymobile.com/vmousedown/) event instead of touchstart.

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){       
    $(document).on('vmousedown', '#index', function(){       
        alert('vmousedown');
    });
});
```

And here's a working jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/vDqdD/4/

Answer (score 2):

For a game it would be better to use the native touch events: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Touch_events. Using them allows you to have a much tighter control than using the convenience events such as "tap".

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try this  [Quo JS](http://quojs.tapquo.com/)  lightweight javascript library for the accurate events. I have found this over few suggestions from SO. It worked wonderfully and very accurate.